# Generate and test update.rdf for firefox addon-sdk

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How do I generate update.rdf for the Firefox addon-sdk and then test it to ensure   everything is working correctly?

Comment: Please briefly explain your query and what you have tried so far. Refer to this: [How to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm not familiar with update.rdf. I only know install.rdf, and you can specify some update urls in there. Is your addon unlisted?